# boost::io_service::strand performance

Tags: multithreading, boost-asio, boost-thread

I am using a boost::io_service to build a thread pool that executes computational jobs in parallel. Some jobs are not allowed to run concurrently, which - I think - is the ideal application of a  boost::io_service::strand. As **the order in which the sequential jobs are executed does not matter**, I am asking, which of the two ways to use the strand I should use:

```
strand.post(bind(jobA...));
```

or

```
io_service.post(strand.wrap(bind(jobA...)))
```

If I understand the boost docs correctly, the first version will insure that the jobs are executed in the same order they were posted, whereas the second version does not give any guarantee.

My question is: Which one is faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the two methods described above interchangeably and it will result in identical results. I doubt very much that there is any performance difference, but if there is, it's in the overhead of the two function (`strand.post` vs `io_service.post`) calls but not in the actual execution of the `io_service` since they both do the same thing under the hood and have the same path of execution.

I would guess that `io_service.post()` requires a handful fewer clock cycles, but in the same breath I'm also guessing that such micro-optimizations are as noticeable in your application as interference from solar radiation and the CPU having to re-execute instructions. I don't even know if that's a real phenomena or not, but it sounded cool when trying to come up with a verbose way of saying, "don't worry about it". If there is in fact a performance difference, please share the benchmarks. *rolls eyes at self*

Comment: So you are are saying (besides, that its does matter) the opposite of Steve Townsend. Why do you think  `io_service.post`are less clock cycles?

Comment: `io_service.post(strand.wrap(bind(jobA...)))` is available on the stack and the compiler can more-easily precompute much of the work runtime effort at compile-time. `strand.post(bind(jobA...))`, somehow the `strand` needs to resolve to the relevant `io_service`.  I don't think there's more than a handful of instructions difference between the two, but in my unmeasured, WAG, I think `io_service.post` is "faster" by an irrelevant quantity of cycles in all workloads where this process is hooked up to either a disk or network. Better performance gains are to be had by cooling your servers more. :)

Comment: The keywords there are "more easily". A sufficiently good compiler _should_ compile both ways down to the same set of instructions. Test and report back to us if you're really that interested in the dozen or so instructions.

Comment: +1 for micro optimizations and test and report back, both are great suggestions.

Comment: @Sean: It result in the same instructions as one of the two methods preserves the order of execution!!!

Comment: You have no control over the way that `io_service` executes calls that have been dispatched to it. `io_service` is free to execute jobs in any order it sees fit and does so in an unspecified way.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I doubt the end performance difference is detectible in your final system, but simplicity combined with functional sufficiency argues for option 1.

It's more comprehensible, and using the `io_service` route does not give you any extra function, while necessarily, since you are indirecting through one extra layer - the `io_service` - adding extra lines of code that must be executed.

The [docs for strand::post](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand/post.html) are clear that using this method already provides the necessary behavioural guarantees at both `io_service` and `strand` levels.

Comment: Yes there is extra code in the second case, but the question for me is: How much does the order-of-exection guarantee cost?

Comment: You won't be able to tell without measuring.  This hardly seems worth the cycles to me, I would bet you have more important performance issues to worry about in a program of this nature.